# Windows Metro SizedChange on Snap

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1

i am having quite trouble with my Images and Canvases when the user tries to snap in a View/App on the Left site. I already declared a method and a delegate on

```
 Window.Current.SizeChanged += OnWindowSizeChanged;
```

But this isn't really cool because I already have a pinchZoom. I really don't want the view to get downsized when the AppWindow gets resized. Is there any Parameter I can set that the view is not resized on that event?

```
 <Grid Height="758" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Width="10000" ManipulationMode="All" x:Name="paper" PointerWheelChanged="scrolled" ManipulationDelta="PaperManipulation" >
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>


            <Image Source="images/page.png" x:Name="backgroundpaper"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="758" Width="10000" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

            <Grid Margin="240,140,0,0"  Height="600" x:Name="canvases" ManipulationMode="All" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>

                <Canvas    Tapped="canvasTapped" Background="Transparent" ManipulationMode="All" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" x:Name="background_canvas" Height="600"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                </Canvas>

               .... // SOME MORE ELEMENTS
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Thanks so far.

Comment: so you don't want to handle snapped view in your app?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I do want the app to be able to get lets say halfscreen but i do not want my images and canvases to get resized within it

Comment: check your  ViewState Code in XAML . Are you setting any width or height to the control/canvas there?

Comment: Yeah! I found out that if i am setting a width, it s not getting resized!!! Thanks, but now it is cut of.

Comment: it will be cut off or you have to resize it but you don't want it right?.

Comment: thanks for your time! so I set the width in xml (see above) and it will not get resized. THATS SUPER. But now it gets cut on the right edge.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39652/discussion-between-asitis-and-a-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check with your code in XAML ? 
I think you set some Width there.

```
  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
            <Storyboard>
                //check your code here in snapped view handling
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```